# $E = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \, | \, x \leq y, \, xy \geq 1 \, y \leq 2\}$, Calculate $\int_E \frac{y^2}{x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, lebesgue-integral

$E = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \, | \, x \leq y, \, xy \geq 1 \, y \leq 2\}$

Calculate $\int_E \frac{y^2}{x^2}$

---

I don't really know how to approach this. What we learned and what I normally do is to rewrite the given equations and put them as the boundaries of the integral, or use cylindrical coordinates. However, latter appraoch doesn't seem to fit.

And I can't get the first one to work because I get equtions like this:

I split the integral into two integrals where in the first one $y \geq 0$ and in the second one $y <0$. But it is something like:

$\int_0^2 \int^y_ {?} \frac{y^2}{x^2} dx dy + \int_{-\infty}^0 \int^?_ {-\infty} \frac{y^2}{x^2} dx dy$

And in the first $?$ it should be: $\{\frac 1 {y} $ if $y \geq \frac 1 {y}\,\,,\,\, 0$ else $\}$.

In the second $?$ it should be: $\{y $ if $y \geq \frac 1 {y}\,\,,\,\, \frac 1 {y}$ else $\}$

But what to with that? Split the integrals again, so that I have 4 in total? This really doesn't seem to be the way to go. How do I solve this integral?

Comment: Did you sketch the region? I think you only need to consider the region in first quadrant.